# Try Catch in Discord.js does not catch

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a command handler which should catch the errors if a error occurs when loading a command, but it does not catch the error. I need this, because my bot would crash any time there is a error and i dont want that.

Here is the code of the module:

```js
for(const file of utilsCommandFiles) {
    try {
    const command = require(`./commands/utils/${file}`)
    console.log(`[INFORMATION] HYPX: Utils-Modul "${command.name}" wurde erfolgreich geladen.`)
    utilsCMDs.set(command.name, command)
    } catch(e) {
        const command = require(`./commands/utils/${file}`)
        console.error(`[ERROR] HYPX: Modul ${command.name} konnte nicht geladen werden.`)
        console.log(e)

    }
}
```

Comment: What does 'does not catch' mean ?

Comment: The exception does not get catched

Comment: So it goes through and i get the stack trace and the bot crashes

Comment: post the stack trace please

Comment: The stack trace is of the error i've done.(I've written some poop in the class which needed to be loaded) So there is no stack trace. It just dont catch the exception

Comment: what happens if you comment out `console.error('[ERROR] HYPX: Modul ${command.name} konnte nicht geladen werden.')` ?

Comment: The stack trace of my error is coming, so the error does not get catched

Comment: ```js
for(const file of utilsCommandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/utils/${file}`)
    try {
    console.log(`[INFORMATION] HYPX: Utils-Modul "${command.name}" wurde erfolgreich geladen.`)
    commands.set(command.name, command)
    } catch(e) {
        //console.error(`[ERROR] HYPX: Modul ${command.name} konnte nicht geladen werden.`)
        console.log(e)

    }
}

``` This is the current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. No need for answer.

```js
for(const file of utilsCommandFiles) {
    try {
    const command = require(`./commands/utils/${file}`)
    commands.set(command.name, command)
    console.log(`[INFORMATION] HYPX: Utils-Modul "${command.name}" wurde erfolgreich geladen.`)
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(`[ERROR] HYPX: Modul konnte nicht geladen werden.`)
        console.log(e)

    }
}
```

I just forgot to `const command = require(`./commands/utils/${file}`)` in the TryCatch Block